# Problema con servidor asyncrono el cual debe mostrar datos en labels c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo un servidor asíncrono el cual recibe datos de otro programa, este al recibirlos los guarda en un `ArrayList` y este `ArrayList` se pasa por un método creado en un `Form` a dicho `Form`, el cual hace un `Split` de los datos y guarda en una variable cada uno para mostrarlos en un `Label` cada uno de estos.

Realiza todo correctamente menos lo de mostrar en los `Label` las variables con mis datos, os dejo el código de la clase servidor (es un ejemplo de internet adaptado a mi proyecto):

```
  public class StateObject
     {
       // Client  socket.  
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //Array
    public ArrayList listaValores = new ArrayList();
     }

     public class AsynchronousSocketListener
    {
    // Thread signal.  
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public static String dinero;
    static ArrayList ListaV = new ArrayList();


    public AsynchronousSocketListener()
    {

    }

    public static void StartListening()
    {
        //Cambiar para que haga rastreo?
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
        Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.  
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.  
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.  
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.  
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Aceptado");
        // Create the state object.  
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
        // from the asynchronous state object.  
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;


        // Read data from the client socket.   
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            //Console.WriteLine(bytesRead);
            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read   
            // more data.  
            content = state.sb.ToString();

            //Console.WriteLine(content);
            ListaV.Add(content);

            for (int i = 0; i < ListaV.Count; i++) {
                //Console.WriteLine("Dentro de la lista "+ListaV[i]);
            }
            string s = (string)ListaV[ListaV.Count - 1];
            Console.WriteLine(s);

            if (ListaV.Count >= 2) {
                Form1 obj = new Form1();
                obj.llamarArray(ListaV);
                ListaV.Clear();
            }

            //Console.WriteLine(content+ "Uno");
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
            {
                // All the data has been read from the   
                // client. Display it on the console.
                //Console.WriteLine(content);
                // Echo the data back to the client.
                //Insertar y obtener  la cantidad

                //Send(handler, content);  
            }
            else
            {
                // Not all data received. Get more.  
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    //Intento de callback
    public static string getTotal()
    {
        return dinero;
    }

    public static void setTotal(string total)
    {
        dinero = total;
        //Thread.CurrentThread.Name.Insert(1,dinero);
    }
    }
```

Es un poco extenso pero es un servidor asyncrono normal y corriente, os dejo tambien mi form donde recibe los datos:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        string cambio = "";
        string introducido = "";
        string apagar = "";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Bitmap img = new Bitmap(Application.StartupPath + @"C:\Imagenes\ Dispay_Definitivo_2.png"); //Ruta_erronea_comentado_por_ahora.
            //this.BackgroundImage = img;
            //this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;

            //  Pantalla completa para el display

           this.Font = SystemFonts.IconTitleFont;
           SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged += new UserPreferenceChangedEventHandler(SystemEvents_UserPreferenceChanged);
           this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);
           this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(100F, 110F); 
           this.PerformAutoScale();



        }

        Point DragCursor;
        Point DragForm;
        bool Dragging;

        public void Total(string Total)
        {

        }

        void SystemEvents_UserPreferenceChanged(object sender, UserPreferenceChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Category == UserPreferenceCategory.Window)
            {
                this.Font = SystemFonts.IconTitleFont; 
            }
        }

        void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged -= new UserPreferenceChangedEventHandler(SystemEvents_UserPreferenceChanged);
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // this.Size = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize;  //"este código permite ajustar la resolucion a pantalla completa"
        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label_Entregado_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Dragging = false; 
        }

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Dragging = true;
            DragCursor = Cursor.Position;
            DragForm = this.Location;
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Dragging == true)
            {
                Point dif = Point.Subtract(Cursor.Position, new Size(DragCursor));
                this.Location = Point.Add(DragForm, new Size(dif));
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void label2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public void llamarArray(ArrayList lista) {
            for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++) {
                string dato = (string)lista[i];
                //Console.WriteLine("array"+dato);

            }
            string lastvalue = (string)lista[lista.Count-1];
            //Console.WriteLine("ultimovalor"+lastvalue);
            string[] valores = lastvalue.Split("\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            Console.WriteLine("1 " + valores[valores.Count() - 1]);
            cambio = valores[valores.Count() - 1];

            label2.Text = cambio;
            labeldevuelto.Text = cambio;
            label2.Invalidate();
            label2.Update();
            MessageBox.Show(label2.Text);
            this.Refresh();
            this.Invalidate();
            Console.WriteLine("2 " + valores[valores.Count() - 2]);
            introducido = valores[valores.Count() - 2];
            label1.Text = introducido;
            labelentregado.Text = introducido;
            MessageBox.Show(label1.Text);
            this.Refresh();
            this.Invalidate();
            Console.WriteLine("3 " + valores[valores.Count() - 3]);
            apagar = valores[valores.Count() - 3];
            label3.Text = apagar;
            labeltotal.Text = apagar;
            MessageBox.Show(label3.Text);
            this.Refresh();
            this.Invalidate();
            Application.DoEvents();

            //foreach (string item in valores) { Console.WriteLine("Valores a colocar" + item); };






        }

        private void label3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {



        }

        private void labelentregado_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Como veis he intentado de todo para refrescar mi Label y el Form para ver si de esta manera consigo ver los datos por pantalla, también he metido MessageBox para saber el valor de los Label después de aplicarle el cambio de texto y me muestra los valores correctamente pero en la aplicación no, os dejo también mi clase Program por si hubiese algo raro ahí, pero no creo:

```
 static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            Thread Formulario = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LanzarFormularioCobro));
            Thread Servidor = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LanzarServidor));
            Servidor.Start();
            Formulario.Start();

            Servidor.Join();
            Formulario.Join();

        }
        public static void LanzarFormularioInicio()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);
            Application.Run(new Form2());
        }

        public static void LanzarFormularioEspera()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);
            Application.Run(new Form2());
        }

        public static void LanzarFormularioCobro()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        public static void LanzarServidor()
        {
            AsynchronousSocketListener.StartListening();
        }

    }
}
```

Por lo que me comentaron en la primera pregunta puede que el programa este en un hilo constantemente y este se congele y por eso no muestra los datos, pero si yo le hago un cambio de texto en el `label_click` si me lo realiza.

Un saludo.

Comment: Perdona entendi mal lo que me comentaste de hacer un ejemplo minimo, borro la anterior

Comment: El problema por cierto es evidente. En tu `ReadCallback` estás creando un nuevo Form (`Form1 obj = new Form1();
                obj.llamarArray(ListaV);`) que no tiene nada que ver con tu Form1 original, son dos instancias diferentes, y por eso no te modifica los labels

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero entonces como puedo llamar al método que esta en mi form1 desde otra clase para pasarle el arraylist que llega a la clase servidor? un saludo

Comment: El tema es bastante problematico, ya que usas un hilo diferente para el servidor y el formulario, y yo probablemente lo haria de una manera totalmemente diferente. Creo que lo normal es que llamaras al servidor desde el propio formulario, y que este devolviera los datos recibidos al form.

Comment: Intentare lo que me propones, no me parece mala idea, pero parece bastante complicado porque no se como llamar al servidor desde el form y que se mantenga operativo, se llamar a los diferentes metodos de la clase servidor pero no se como montar un server en el form, ¿tendrias algun ejemplo en el que me pudiera fijar? un saludo.

Comment: Todo depende mucho de lo que necesites. Pero te recomiendo no usar Thread, que es una clase complicada, y que leas sobre [programación asíncrona](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) que es la manera en la que yo orientaría esto.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, el proyecto que estoy haciendo ha pasado por manos de muchos programadores y es un proyecto grande por lo que me es muy dificil cambiar radicalmente la arquitectura del proyecto ahora mismo, si pudieras guiarme hacia el tema de llamar al servidor desde el form para poder tirar con lo que tengo de momento y en un futuro cambiar la arquitectura del proyecto, un saludo.

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar? Saludos :D